# How can I extract data from multiple Word documents to excel rows based on keywords using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I got this VBA code from [@macropod](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-extracting-ms-word-form-data-into-excel-table.1067822/) to extract data from various Word files from the folder that is in the "strFolder" variable of the VBA code below, but I can only extract data that is in front of the keyword, as in the term "TRABALHO" (attached image) the VBA code extracts the content from the front, but I can't extract data from below, for example in: "CONSTATAÇÃO" I can't extract the text from below, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it. Just below I also put a capture of the document that I have to use to extract the data.

[IMAGE - Word Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxxxh.png)

```
Sub GetData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBA Editor's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String, strOut As String, StrFnd
strFolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Macro VBA - Trabalhos Sequenciais\Trabalhos\"
StrFnd = Array("", "", "TRABALHO", "SEQUENCIAL", "REGISTRO", "DATA DA IMPLEMENTAÇÃO", "PRAZO PARA EFETIVAÇÃO", _
"DATA DA EFETIVAÇÃO", "RESPONSÁVEL PELA ANÁLISE", "REVISOR", "CONSTATAÇÃO")
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet: r = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  r = r + 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  WkSht.Cells(r, 1).Value = Split(strFile, ".doc")(0)
  With wdDoc
    For c = 2 To UBound(StrFnd)
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .Format = False
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .Text = StrFnd(c)
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found = True Then
          .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
          .Start = .Start + Len(StrFnd(c))
          strOut = Trim(Replace(Replace(Replace(Split(.Text, vbCr)(0), vbTab, " "), Chr(11), " "), Chr(160), " "))
          Do While strOut = ""
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
            strOut = Trim(Replace(Replace(Replace(Split(.Text, vbCr)(0), vbTab, " "), Chr(11), " "), Chr(160), " "))
          Loop
          WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = strOut
        End If
      End With
    Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: «I made this code» Telling porkies won't win you any friends here. You lifted code ***I*** wrote from somewhere like https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-extracting-ms-word-form-data-into-excel-table.1067822/ and made a few edits...  In any event, you don't need to use Find for this - all you need do is learn how to use table cell references!

Comment: @macropod I'm sorry it was my expression error, I didn't really create this VBA, because I don't really understand how it works, I expressed myself badly.

Comment: @macropod I made some edits mentioning the original code post link, again sorry for my misplaced expression.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your data are in various cells in the first 3 tables in the document. In that case, you need something like:

```
Sub GetData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBA Editor's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
strFolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Macro VBA - Trabalhos Sequenciais\Trabalhos\"
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet: r = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  r = r + 1: c = 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(strFile, ".doc")(0)
  With wdDoc
    With .Tables(1)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(1, 1).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(1, 2).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(1, 3).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
    End With
    With .Tables(2)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(1, 2).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(1, 4).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(2, 2).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(3, 2).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(4, 2).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
    End With
    With .Tables(3)
      Set wdRng = .Cells(2, 1).Range: c = c + 1
      WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer how to extract data from multiple word files and write it to text file.

Following is the code to extract multiple word files from multiple folders and sub folders

```
import glob
import docx2txt as d2t


input_dir=r"D:\Doc scraping\xyz"                      
filepaths=list(glob.glob(input_dir+"\**\*.docx", recursive=True))

def extract_data_from_docx(path_to_file, get_text=False):

text = d2t.process(path_to_file) 

 if(get_text):       #Defining a function to extract text from docx file
    return text
data=""

for filepath in filepaths:

  data = data + extract_data_from_docx(filepath, get_text=True)     

print(data)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).